# Xcode 8 : provisioning profiles 'Create' button disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

After I clicked on 'Create' button for iOS development provisioning profile in xcode 8, the button just disappeared. And it didn't appear below too. Attached is the screenshot of what I see. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!!!!

[image]

Comment: Have you created any certificate yourself.

Comment: From XCode 8, apple provides you an ease to automatically create development profiles. Try that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means you already have a development certificate on that Mac, so there is no need to create one. You don't need to create more than one.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!!! I'm still not able to open the apps in my phone but at least figured out a way to install them. You guys rock!